# How do I force cabal to give me more meaningful error messages?

Tags: haskell, cabal

On trying to install Pandoc, I see:

```
....
/usr/local/bin/ghc --make -o dist/build/pandoc/pandoc -hide-all-packages -fbuilding-cabal-package -package-conf dist/package.conf.inplace -i -idist/build/pandoc/pandoc-tmp -isrc -idist/build/autogen -Idist/build/autogen -Idist/build/pandoc/pandoc-tmp -optP-include -optPdist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -odir dist/build/pandoc/pandoc-tmp -hidir dist/build/pandoc/pandoc-tmp -stubdir dist/build/pandoc/pandoc-tmp -package-id HTTP-4000.2.2-b514c58971c354891f971c2309e33000 -package-id base-4.5.0.0-f76ceb9607ba9bd4fcfb9c7b92d8cfe1 -package-id base64-bytestring-0.1.1.0-9a13565ae6900096f49fed9275055262 -package-id blaze-html-0.4.3.1-5d598387646df0193836b494a162a2d4 -package-id bytestring-0.9.2.1-4adca9710b1386944aaca5a7886ef98f -package-id citeproc-hs-0.3.4-cbb3e9b1b273d47e103e907ec1bdc35b -package-id containers-0.4.2.1-7c54595400348f577b3b4a45691c5afd -package-id directory-1.1.0.2-8b4f1910e60eb4e736abc40d5bcff870 -package-id extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.4-d27a1ac47e54880cae007cceceb41580 -package-id filepath-1.3.0.0-674b8a582fb49f1c9724f50a6a5d5768 -package-id highlighting-kate-0.5.0.5-a1ba824bf441c42c048d12abbb7076f2 -package-id json-0.5-95bdbc43daf81b2bce0748d1aaa9c3a3 -package-id mtl-2.0.1.0-e356d8b8100adb575c81fb037ade5369 -package-id network-2.3.0.11-aad575b3bc998a0814d4406663f72a07 -package-id old-locale-1.0.0.4-29bd50ed2bb4a20928338f52e4ab1b71 -package-id pandoc-types-1.9.1-861bbcdbc020a96a664261e3dea501f4 -package-id parsec-3.1.2-ddd167c649705555d9a0c4e2b3751077 -package-id process-1.1.0.1-91185c964ab744c1f3cbca1863d2ba45 -package-id random-1.0.1.1-3bece392c9f5221263ed25c90c28e1ec -package-id syb-0.3.6-05925f4440bc3fbb54d5c12bac109e49 -package-id tagsoup-0.12.6-57ca8a2db7339ea6237481f4729e5e0f -package-id temporary-1.1.2.3-e69a9bd7a2d9d49de929e9a0be4ed42a -package-id texmath-0.6.0.3-2e5a17474805a2f6b73558e3a71ad38b -package-id time-1.4-3e186a51d3674e5d65b5a7925db3d3a7 -package-id utf8-string-0.3.7-528cea24d4cad2c1cb19a75d1ad8976c -package-id xml-1.3.12-d665e5a084b52511c150438a3c9fb8d1 -package-id zip-archive-0.1.1.7-463904d956f1052cc58a2c9e5deeee2c -package-id zlib-0.5.3.3-9ed15628a121b3b57f97b7acc02bf5d9 -O -O2 -Wall -fno-warn-unused-do-bind -dno-debug-output -XHaskell98 -XCPP src/pandoc.hs
[39 of 42] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Readers.Markdown ( src/Text/Pandoc/Readers/Markdown.hs, dist/build/pandoc/pandoc-tmp/Text/Pandoc/Readers/Markdown.o )

cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
pandoc-1.9.1.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 11
```

If I try to run that command, it works without any problems. So why do I see `ExitFailure 11`? How do I get cabal to give me a decent error message?

As a side note: I love Haskell, but cabal is awful. We need a better package manager.

Comment: "Cabal is a package and build system. Cabal is only involved in the creation of packages and the building of their contents. It does not manage packages." -- http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal . `cabal-install` is the "package mangager", except that it's not very full featured. Cabal works great at what it does, cabal-install, not so much. See also http://ivanmiljenovic.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/repeat-after-me-cabal-is-not-a-package-manager/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `--verbose=3` flag.